# I will be traveling from Tijuana to Juarez. Can I use my ID to board the plane?

Tags: mexico, identity-cards

Can I board a flight from Tijuana to Juarez without a passport and only using a California ID?

Answer (score 3):

You can board a flight in Mexico with just your California ID but you will also need a Mexican Tourist Card (FMM). You can obtain one at the airport by filling out the necessary paperwork or doing it online. The cost is $500 pesos or $24USD. I highly recommend checking https://www.gob.mx/en/index.

Please note you will need to at least know or have access to your passport number to fill out the form for the FMM.

Comment: If a US citizen is in Mexico less than seven days, the paperwork is no charge.  One one of my exits, they tried to charge me $25 (not $24) for more than seven days because when I entered, the guy put a false date on my card.  Also, when I boarded a plane from MEX to NLD, I had the proper papers, but no one asked to see them.